# Home page - registration form blocks the dropdown menu

Tags: bug, design

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open https://stackoverflow.com/ in a new browser session. I believe this is one way to make Stack Overflow show the home page registration form.
2. Click on any of the menu items between the search box and the <kbd>Log In</kbd> button ([these items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5jBO.gif))
3. Menu item is highlighted but no menu is visible.
4. Scroll past the registration form and the menu is visible.

Note that they are visible on the question view. This leads me to believe this is a CSS bug.

In the following demo, we can see that the menu item before the <kbd>Log In</kbd> button is highlighted when clicked, but we need to scroll down in order to use it.

[image]

Comment: @Vega I understand that the inbox and achievements menus are not meant for visitors, but in the screenshot, I was trying to access another community through the dropdown menu.

Comment: It's appearing fine for me; the blue box is placed vertically below the top bar in Chrome 66 and doesn't obscure it. This is certainly *not* intended behaviour... it'd be really user-hostile if this was intended. Which web browser are you using?

Comment: I think you need to make a GIF-animation to demo this. Took me a while to reproduce this (Firefox 60).

Comment: @VadimKotov Hi, thank you for the comment. I will prepare one asap.